# What is preventing eslint from installing based on my error code?

Tags: terminal, atom-editor, lint, linter

I am following a Udemy course and the first app we are building through Atom is called albums. I have installed linter and linter-eslint in Atom, but running this code:

npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding
leads to an incomplete install.

My first line reads:

deprecated eslint-plugin-class-property@1.1.0: please use eslint-plugin-babel and babel/semi

But the second line of my log reads:

@babel/plugin-check-constants@7.0.0-beta.38 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.38 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

So after that, every line starts off with SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY.

So I am just trying to see what I may be missing or if this even is a problem?